# Solving equation: non-linear

Tags: nonlinear-system

I am trying to find the values of x, y and z having these equations. a, b and c are constants.
$$
\begin{cases}
a = (\frac y x)^{1/2} \cdot \frac {x+y} x
\\
b = (\frac z x)^{1/2} \cdot \frac {z+x} x
\\
c = (\frac  y z)^{1/2} \cdot \frac {y+z} z
\end{cases} $$
I have no idea how to find values of x, y and z. I have tried to solve them by multiplication, division by all I get in return is another set of equations.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Perhaps you have a  typo in the denominator in the first line.

Comment: Yes it is, I have corrected. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Firstly, I am no major in Mathematics, a chemist. I am stuck at a problem like this, which I do not know how to solve. Even I do not know what type of problem is this. I have tried to solve it in pen and paper, but to no avail. This was my try. I thought I could ask for some help here.

Comment: Hmm... your equations looks strange and I suspect there are more typos. The 1st and 2nd equations are cubic equations in $\sqrt{y/x}$ and $\sqrt{z/x}$. In principle, you can express $y/x$ solely in terms of $a$, $z/x$ solely in terms of $b$. The 3rd equation becomes either redundant or inconsistent....

Comment: @achillehui I have checked again. No typos.

Comment: In this case, you have 3 equations of the form $t^3 + t = p$. If you throw the command `Solve[ t^3 + t = p, {t}]` to [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B+t%5E3+%2B+t+%3D+p%2C+%7Bt%7D%5D), it will give you a complicated expression for the 3 roots of polynomial. Only the first one is real and the one you need 
$$t = \frac{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 p^2 + 4} + 9 p}}{\sqrt[3]{2}\,3^{2/3} } - \frac{\sqrt[3]{\frac23}}{\sqrt[3]{\sqrt{3} \sqrt{27 p^2 + 4} + 9 p}}$$

Comment: This is a strange problem. Being a chemist, may be you could tell if all  $(a,b,c,x,y,z)$ are positive.

Comment: From the intuition, x, y, z should come positive. From the calculated values, a, b or c may be negative.